# Combining rows based on conditions and saving others (in R)

Tags: r, row, tidyverse

I have a question regarding combining columns based on two conditions.

I have two datasets from an experiment where participants had to type in a code, answer about their gender and eyetracking data was documented. The experiment happened twice (first: random1, second: random2).

```
eye <- c(1000,230,250,400)
gender <- c(1,2,1,2)
code <- c("ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL")
random1 <- data.frame(code,gender,eye)

eye2 <- c(100,250,230,450)
gender2 <- c(1,1,2,2)
code2 <- c("ABC","DEF","JKL","XYZ")
random2 <- data.frame(code2,gender2,eye2)
```

Now I want to combine the two dataframes. For all rows where code and gender match, the rows should be combined (so columns added). Code and gender variables of those two rows should become one each (gender3 and code3) and the eyetracking data should be split up into eye_first for random1 and eye_second for random2.

For all rows where there was not found a perfect match for their code and gender values, a new dataset with all of these rows should exist.

```
#this is what the combined data looks like
gender3 <- c(1,2)
eye_first <- c(1000,400)
eye_second <- c(100, 230)
code3 <- c("ABC", "JKL")
random3 <- data.frame(code3,gender3,eye_first,eye_second)

#this is what the data without match should look like
gender4 <- c(2,1,2)
eye4 <- c(230,250,450)
code4 <- c("DEF","GHI","XYZ")
random4 <- data.frame(code4,gender4,eye4)
```

I would greatly appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same column names for your 2 data.frames and use `merge`

```r
random1 <- data.frame(code = code, gender = gender, eye = eye)
random2 <- data.frame(code = code2, gender = gender2, eye = eye2)

df <- merge(random1, random2, by = c("code", "gender"), suffixes = c("_first", "_second"))
```

For your second request, you can use `anti_join` from `dplyr`

```r
df2 <- merge(random1, random2, by = c("code", "gender"), suffixes = c("_first", "_second"), all = TRUE) # all = TRUE : keep rows with ids that are only in one of the 2 data.frame

library(dplyr)

anti_join(df2, df, by = c("code", "gender"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What exactly does anti-join do in this context?

Comment: `anti_join(x, y)` returns all rows from `x` where there are not matching values in `y`, keeping just columns from `x`.